# UIElement.Visibility property performance

Tags: c#, performance, xaml, set, visibility

When you're changing the value of Visibility property on a `UIElement` object, is it more efficient to check before the value and set the new one only if different from the current

```
if(MyUIElement.Visibility != Visibility.Collapsed)
    MyUIElement.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

or set the new value in each case?

```
MyUIElement.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

I often wonder about this problem, because Visibility property should affect UI, so a check could be more efficient, but never found on the web anything well argued.

Thanks

Comment: Setting the property only affects the UI when it actually changes. Setting to Collapsed when it is already Collapsed will not result in any re-rendering of the element.

Comment: So actually the framework checks the value in background for me? Does this also applies to other common use properties of UI Controls?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Yes, that's a basic feature of all dependency properties.